# When is the tensor product commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra

I am working with the the tensor product $-\otimes_R -$ over some noncommutative ring $R$. Is the tensor product always commutative if $R$ is commutative? (That is: Is it true that $M \otimes_R N \cong N \otimes_R M$ for all $M$ and $N$?) If so, can the tensor product be commutative if $R$ is noncommutative?

Comment: The thing is, if $R$ is not commutative, $M\otimes_R N$ makes sense only if $M$ is a right $R$-module and $N$ a left $R$-module. Hence the tensor product is not commutative, but worse, it is defined for only one way.

Comment: Well, I suppose we could consider $M,\,N$ to be $R$-$R$- bimodules?

Comment: @SamWilliams what do you mean by $R-R- bimodules.$ do you mean that each  one is $R-$module?

Comment: @Smart20: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bimodule for the definition of an $R$-$R$-bimodule (or, more generally, an $R$-$S$-bimodule; it is often less confusing to work in the general setting).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tensor product's commutativity depends on the commutativity of the elements. If the ring is commutative, the tensor product is as well. If the ring R is non-commutative, the tensor product will only be commutative over the commutative sub-ring of R. There will always be tensors over the ring that will not commute if R is non-commutative.

Comment: Many thanks! I was thinking along those lines but was unsure.

Comment: Actually, even if $R$ is commutative, then the tensor product is not always commutative! Indeed, we are talking about $R$-$R$-bimodules here, not about $R$-modules (= $R$-$R$-bimodules satisfying the identity $rm = mr$). In $M \otimes_R N$, you "use up" the right $R$-module structure on $M$ and the left $R$-module structure on $N$ for tensoring, whereas in $N \otimes_R M$ it is the "other two" structures that you are using. The results can easily be non-isomorphic.

Comment: @darijgrinberg could you please give us a concrete example?

Comment: @darijgrinberg  I did not fully understand your comment. Is not your comment contradicts the answers to that question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759486/why-is-mathbbz-m-otimes-mathbbz-mathbbz-mathbbz-otimes-ma/3759493#3759493 of mine?

Comment: @Smart20: I'll provide an example when I find the time, but there is surely no contradiction with the question you link, since that question concerns modules rather than bimodules.

Comment: Here is an explicit example for how $M \otimes_R N$ can fail to be isomorphic to $N \otimes_R M$. Let $K$ be a field, and let $R$ be the polynomial ring $K\left[X\right]$. Let $f : R \to K$ be the $K$-algebra homomorphism that sends $X$ to $0$ (and thus sends each polynomial in $R$ to its constant term). Let $M$ be the $R$-$R$-bimodule whose ground set is $K$ (as abelian group), with $R$ acting on the left via identity and on the right via $f$ (that is, $rm = r \cdot m$ and $mr = m \cdot f\left(r\right)$ for all $r \in R$ and $m \in M$). Let $N$ be ...

Comment: ... the $R$-$R$-bimodule whose ground set is $K$ (as abelian group), with $R$ acting on the right via identity and on the left via $f$. Then, $M \otimes_R N \cong M \otimes_K N$ as an $R$-$R$-bimodule, with $R$ acting on both sides via identity. Meanwhile, $N \otimes_R M$ is congruent to the $R$-$R$-bimodule whose ground set is $R$ and that has $R$ act on both sides via $f$. You can easily check that these two $R$-$R$-bimodules $M \otimes_R N$ and $N \otimes_R M$ are not isomorphic.