# Why do we say that the tensor product of vector spaces is commutative, but the tensor product of vectors is not?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology, tensor-products, tensors, noncommutative-algebra

The Wikipedia article on the tensor product [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Commutativity_as_vector_space_operation)

> The tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is commutative in the sense that there is a canonical isomorphism V ⊗ W ≅ W ⊗ V that maps v ⊗ w to w ⊗ v.

> On the other hand, even when $V = W$, the tensor product of vectors is not commutative; that is v ⊗ w ≠ w ⊗ v in general.

I've seen similar usage in other sources.

I'm a little confused by this usage of the word "commutative". It seems to me that the situations for the tensor product of vectors and for the tensor product of vector spaces are equivalent: in both cases, the tensor product in one order and the tensor product in the other order are not directly equal, but they are equivalent up to canonical isomorphism.

So why do we say that the tensor product of vectors is not commutative, but the tensor product of vector spaces is? Doesn't consistency of terminology require that we either say that both operations are commutative, or neither is, depending on whether we are allowing equivalence up to canonical isomorphism?

It's possible that I'm reading too much into the distinction between "tensor product of vectors" and "tensor product of vector spaces" in the Wikipedia article's presentation, and the answer is simply that there's one sense in which both operations are commutative and another sense in which neither operation is.

Comment: In place of equality, it is replaced with isomorphism. I suppose one can say "is _______ in the sense of..." and follow that by anything coupled with an equivalence relation.

Comment: @DavidP What is "it"? The tensor product of vectors, or of vector spaces, or both?

Comment: "It" is equality.

Comment: @DavidP Equality of tensor products of vectors written different order, or equality of tensor products of vector spaces written in different order?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Equality regarding sets, vector spaces, elements of sets and vector spaces is well understood. $\mathbb R^2=\mathbb R^2$, $(1,2)=(1,2)$, $e^3=e^3$. $\mathbb R\times \mathbb Z \neq \mathbb Z\times \mathbb R$, $(2,3)\neq (3,2)$

Comment: Is your concern unique to the tensor product? What about the cartesian product? It commutes up to iso (bijection), so $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$, but of course $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}\ne\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $(\pi,2)\ne(2,\pi)$. There's two different notions of commutativity at play here: *commutativity-up-to-equality* and *commutativity-up-to-iso*. We could use different words, say *commutativity1* and *commutativity2*, but it makes sense to use one word since in both cases we're talking about stuff switching places.

Comment: @blargoner I agree, but this notion of "commutativity up to isomorphism" is pretty trivial, because pretty much *any* mathematical operation at all with multiple arguments is "commutative up to isomorphism" in this sense. So I'm wondering whether there's any *nontrivial* sense in which the tensor product of vector spaces is a commutative operation.

Comment: @blargoner I think the answer that I've come down to is "No, it isn't really useful (i.e. nontrivial) to say that the tensor product of vector spaces is 'commutative up to isomorphism'." We usually use the word "commutative" in the context of binary operations where both arguments come from the same set, but as I discuss in my answer below, for the tensor product of vector spaces it's more useful to think of the two input vector spaces as being distinct, in the sense of "not canonically isomorphic". So the tensor product operation is only "commutative up to isomorphism" in the trivial way ...

Comment: ... that all operations with multiple arguments are.

Comment: I disagree with your view that commutativity up to iso is trivial or universal. Certainly it's not a deep property, but it can fail in other settings (like tensor products of modules over rings, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351549/when-is-the-tensor-product-commutative#comment7734210_1351561) and other posts on the site). Knowing that it's true for vector spaces is useful. I don't find your other answer satisfying but don't have time to get into it.

Comment: @blargoner Hm, interesting, thanks for that info. I don’t know anything about tensor products of modules, but I’m now thinking that the “commutativity” (up to isomorphism) of the tensor product of vector spaces is much deeper and less trivial than I’d believed, although I don’t fully understand exactly what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $v,w\in V,\ v\neq w$ the products $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ are two different elements of $V\otimes V$. It is true that there is an automorphism $f$ of $V\otimes V$ exchanging the factors, but even then we only have $v\otimes w=f(w\otimes v).$ There is no good sense in which this operation is commutative.

On the other hand, for a pair abstract vector spaces, without something like a larger vector space containing them both, being canonically isomorphic is as close to being 'equal' as we can get.

I suppose your confusion stems from trying to interpret the above statement directly and treating $V\otimes W$ and $W\otimes V$ as equal, and hence treating expressions like $v\otimes w$ as elements of both of these spaces in the most literal way.

Comment: So would you agree with the following statement? $v \otimes w$ and $w \otimes v$ are "equivalent" in the same sense that $V \otimes W$ and $W \otimes V$ are "equivalent", i.e. up to canonical isomorphism. However, in the case of vectors, there is a much *better* sense in which $v \otimes w$ and $w \otimes v$ could actually be *equal*, but this sense of equality is not satisfied for the tensor product of vectors. So the existence of an improved sense of equality for the tensor product of vectors means that we should reserve the notion of "commutativity" for that improved sense, whereas for ...

Comment: ... the tensor product of vector spaces it's reasonable to more loosely apply the word "commutativity" to the weaker sense of equivalence up to isomorphism, because that's the strongest notion of equivalence available. So even though the tensor product of vectors and of vector spaces are in some sense "equally commutative" (i.e. up to isomorphism), we should only apply that word to the latter case.

Comment: @tparker No, I wouldn't agree that $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ are equivalent 'up to canonical isomorphism'. You can't just take an automorphism and apply it to one of these elements and not the other. Elements of a vector space are not equivalent if they are mapped to one another by some automorphism. If for some reason you want to treat such elements as equal, you should consider the quotient of $V\otimes V$ by the subgroup of automorphisms generated by $f$. In fact, people do study such objects, in your case this would be the second graded piece of the symmetric algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Upon further reflection, here's how I think about this. Warning: I'm coming at this from a physicist's perspective, and I suspect that mathematicians won't like this approach, but I think it's useful for physicists.

The tensor product $V \otimes W$ of two vector spaces is best thought of as inputting two *different* vector spaces $V$ and $W$. They might happen to be isomorphic, but there's no *canonical* isomorphism between them; any such isomorphism would give additional algebraic structure beyond that of the tensor product itself.

So you shouldn't think about putting the exact same vector space $V$ into both slots of a tensor product. Instead, it's better to think of them as two different vector spaces - call them $V_A$ and $V_B$ - which might happen to be isomorphic, but can't be identically equal. Plugging the same vector space $V$ into both slots is essentially equivalent to specifying a canonical isomorphism between the two input spaces, but (as mentioned above) this is best thought of as imposing additional structure beyond that of the tensor product itself.

The fundamental "point" of the tensor product is to start from a collection of "buckets" of vectors (each bucket being a different vector space) and take linear combinations of products of exactly one vector from each bucket, while tracking which bucket each vector came from. Instead of tracking this by the order in which the vectors are listed, we could just as easily use subscripts or something: instead of $v \otimes w$, we could write $v_A w_B$. Then any tensor product operators like $X_A Y_B$ act within each bucket, e.g. $(X_A Y_B)(v_A w_B) = (X_A v_A)(Y_B w_B)$. Written this way, it's clear that the order doesn't really matter, as long as we carry the subscript "bucket labels" along with each vector or operator: $v_A w_B = w_B v_A$, but $v_A w_B \neq w_A v_B$; indeed, the latter expression isn't even well-defined without specifying an isomorphism between $V_A$ and $V_B$.

So if you think of each input vector as carrying around its "bucket" index internally, then the tensor product of vectors is trivially commutative, and if you don't, then the notion of interchanging the order of vectors within a tensor product isn't well-defined (without separately specifying an isomorphism between the input vector spaces).